# Posting image in cell, work with cURL command, but does not in Python

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

When I use this :

```
curl --ssl-no-revoke -H "Authorization: Bearer $token$" -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -H "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='IMG_6805.JPG'"-H "Content-Length: 9930" -X POST "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/$sheetID$/rows/$rowID$/columns/$columnID$/cellimages?altText=test" --data-binary @IMG_6805.JPG
```

I get that response:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

followed by :

```
{"message":"SUCCESS","resultCode":0,"result":[{"id":3118469427160964,"rowNumber":1,"expanded":true,"createdAt":"2022-05....etc
```

and the image appear in the cell.

But if I use

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %token%',
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=\'%picfile%\'',
    # 'Content-Length': 'FILE_SIZE',
}

params = {
    'altText': 'test',
}

with open('%picfile%', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().replace(b'\n', b'')

response = requests.post('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/%sheetid%/rows/%rowid%/columns/%columnid%/cellimages', params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
```

I get the following error

```
ErrorCode:5463
Message: An error occurred while trying to process our image, It may be corrupt, too large to process, or an unsupported format.
```

Here is the code

```
import requests

f='IMG_6763.JPG'


sheetid = '7609187174770564'


headersPost= {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token$',
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=\''+f+'\'' ,
    'Content-Lenght':'FILE_SIZE',
}    
params={
    'altText': 'lien'
}
print(headersPost)

print(params)

with open(f,'rb') as p:
    data=p.read().replace(b'\n',b'')


rpost=requests.post('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/7609187174770564/rows/3118469427160964/columns/5324051199616900/cellimages',params=params,headers=headersPost,data=data,stream=True)

print(rpost.text)
#rpost.raise_for_status()
```

The goal is to post in the columns a picture taht is on my computeur. I don't want to attach the file to the row (it is actually already attached).  I want to see the picture in a cell so it gives a preview of what is attached to the row.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [Smartsheet Python SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk) for this? The [docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#add-image-to-cell) provide a code example for the `Cells.add_image_to_cell` operation in the SDK that does what you're trying to do.

Comment: My inexperience to work with SDK actually. I have a hard time geting start with it. on the other hand,  I've manage a work around. Not elegent. but fonctionnal.  I actualy build  a batch script in my Python script, execute it, and delete it.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I understand that using an SDK is challenging when you're not used to doing so. However, I'd strongly encourage you to learn how to use SDKs -- it'll save you a **ton** of time over the course of your career, compared to writing code that directly uses APIs. Not investing time to learn how to use SDKs would be like saying "I don't want to learn how to drive a car, it's too complicated -- I can just walk everywhere." Sure, there's a learning curve initially -- but once you learn to drive it'll save you so much time compared to walking! Just my two cents, FWIW. :)

Comment: I understand.  It is a strong I want to add to my bow.  It was a time issue at that moment.  I'll investigate the SDK soon.  Any reading materials you can point me towards ?

Comment: Glad to hear it! API docs will contain specific info on where to find the SDKs and how to use them. In the Smartsheet API docs, start with the [SDKs and Sample Code](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#sdks-and-sample-code) section. The sample code pane in that section shows you the `pip` command for installing the SDK, & sample code for initializing the client within your code. Clicking the [smartsheet-python-sdk](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk) link takes you to the SDK on GitHub, which contains more info on *Getting Started* with the SDK.

Comment: You might also want to check out a developer-focused site I've been putting together recently: [apinewbies.com](https://www.apinewbies.com). In particular, the [Developer Resources](https://www.apinewbies.com/developer-resources) page contains a section about SDKs. This site is still a work-in-progress but I'll be adding more to it in the days ahead. Hope it's helpful!

Comment: Hey, little follow up. I finally manage to work with the SDK. It actually had a import error in the "types.py" file probably sue to my version of python.  The import was "import collections" and then it use "collections.MutableSequece" in the class argument.  I had to change the import part for "from collections.abc import MutableSequence"
It is easier to use when it works as intendend.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Chris. Yes -- I ran into that issue recently as well. Looks like it's already been reported (https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues/173) so hopefully Smartsheet fixes it soon. FWIW, it's unusual for an SDK to have a problem like this -- usually using an SDK is a smooth process.